# Не находит сходство, хотя они есть. массивы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, такая проблема. делаю массив в массиве и сравниваю сходство, но не находит хотя они есть) В чем может быть проблема ?

```
        foreach ($mail_all as $value_mail) {
            foreach ($services as $value_users) {

                if ($value_mail == $value_users['email']) {
 echo "Есть сходство";

                } else {
                                        echo "Нету";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Скорее всего, код вернул для одной пары совпадение, а для всех остальных случаев - "нету".

Comment: Даже если есть одно совпадение, не выводит, есть сходство.

Comment: Тогда, скорее всего, вы сравниваете что-то не то. Хотя я все равно думаю, что там проблема в результатах, этот код будет выводить 625 строк при двух массивах по 25 элементов.

Comment: А не в $value_mail ли проблема? Эта переменная точно не массив? Не надо ли так сделать: if ($value_mail[0] == $value_users['email'])?

Answer (score 1):

Значит есть различия , пробелы , разные кодировки . 
Попробуйте поискать в массиве нативным [array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) , ну или если с точки зрения изучения проблемы то можете сравнить процент схожести искомого с помощью [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
foreach ( $services as $value_users ) {
    if ( in_array( $value_users['email'], $mail_all ) ) {
        echo "Найдено совпадение!";
        break;
    }
}
```